# How to add new line in php echo

Tags: php, nl2br

The text of story content in my database is:

`I want to add\r\nnew line`

(no quote)

When I use:

```
echo nl2br($story->getStoryContent());
```

to replace the `\r\n` with `br`, it doesn't work. The browser still display `\r\n`. When I view source, the `\r\n` is still there and `br` is nowhere to be found also. This is weird because when I test the function `nl2br` with simple code like:

```
echo nl2br("Welcome\r\nThis is my HTML document");
```

it does work. Would you please tell me why it didn't work? Thank you so much.

Comment: have you tried `echo preg_replace('/\r\n/', '<br/>', $story->getStoryContent());`?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried your suggestion but it doesn't work.

Comment: Then it seems you are not looking for `\r\n`. Try the same method and look for `PHP_EOL` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following snippet uses a technique that you may like better, as follows:

```
<?php

$example = "\n\rSome Kind\r of \nText\n\n";


$replace = array("\r\n", "\n\r", "\r", "\n");
$subs    = array("","","","");

$text = str_replace($replace, $subs, $example );
var_dump($text); // "Some Kind of Text"
```

Live demo **[here](http://3v4l.org/DnsfP)**

I doubt that you need "\n\r" but I left it in just in case you feel it is really necessary.
This works by having an array of line termination strings to be replaced with an empty string in each case.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer is pretty simple. I simply use

```
$text = $this->storyContent;
$text = str_replace("\\r\\n","<br>",$text);
$text = str_replace("\\n\\r","<br>",$text);
$text = str_replace("\\r","<br>",$text);
$text = str_replace("\\n","<br>",$text);
```